# Do crawlers require a robots.txt file before indexing content?

Tags: robots.txt

Do you need a robots.txt file for the crawlers to index your site, or it is just to disallow any content that you don't want crawlers to index?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a robots.txt your website will get indexed. The robots.txt file are just some directions for (nice) crawlers on what not to crawl.

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Please also note that there are aggressive crawlers out there that just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

You may also find [404's in your error logs](http://drupal.org/node/7889) if you don't have a robots.txt in place, if you want to avoid those just create a blank file named robots.txt in your sites root.

Answer (score 2):

A robots.txt file can also be used to provide a link to the sitemap.xml file. That file should contain links to all the pages on your site.